# Problem Wifi connection Lubunto on Aspire One 0751h

Tags: lubuntu

I have a problem with Lubunto on my netbook.
I installed Lubunto version 15 and I don't visualize the list of wifi .
I try to add nm-applet but nothing.
What I can do?
Sorry for bad english I hope you understand.
Bye

Comment: May be nm-applet is broken.

Did you try going to network-connections through dash or menu and check if the networks are visible?